# loop sucessivos em Assembly

Tags: assembly

Estou estudando Assembly porem estou com muita dificuldade, tenho que resolver um exercício porem não entendi o que fazer.

"Fazer um loop para subtrações sucessivas ate negativo. load, sub."

Alguém pode me ajudar.

Comment: Qual assembly? x86? Quais operações permitidas? Devo subtrair o quê do quê?

Comment: Só precisa indicar as posições de memoria e acessar com o código.

Comment: vou fornecer os valores iniciais, também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando o `MOV` do conjunto de instruções do x86 você pode recuperar uma palavra (WORD, 2 bytes) memória a partir de um endereço. Supomos que no endereço `0200` e `0201` esteja armazenado o valor para AX, e `0202` e `0203` esteja armazenado o valor para BX.

```
 072C:0100     MOV AX,[0200]
 072C:0103     MOV BX,[0202]
```

Veja que eu incrementei duas posições pois AX é um WORD com dois bytes. Você pode inicializar os endereços com o `mov` também, por exemplo:

```
MOV WORD PTR [0200],0005
MOV WORD PTR [0202],0002
```

O resultado no endereço `0200` será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo

```
0200 05
0201 00
0202 02
0203 00
```

Lembra-se que a ordem é sempre invertida mas ao recuperar o dado com mov o dado volta corretamente como:

```
byte byte    word

0201 0200 -> 0005
0203 0202 -> 0002
```

O código a seguir é para realizar o LOOP sucessivo subtraindo de ambas variaveis em `AX e BX`, sendo `AX - BX`, logo deve `BX < AX`, continuando no endereço `0107`

```
 072C:0107     SUB AX,0001
 072C:010A     SUB BX,0001
 072C:010D     JNZ 107
 072C:010F     INT 20
```

Enquanto `BX` for diferente de zero, ou seja, se a FLAG ZERO (que indica que a última operação resultou em zero) for falsa, o fluxo volta para o endereço `0107 SUB AX`.

A seguir o código final para o programa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encerrando com a chamada a interrupção `INT 20`, para devolver o controle do programa para o sistema operacional, e impedindo que o programa execute lixo.

**Observação**

Aqui eu utilizei `SUB`, mas você poderia utilizar `DEC`, já que você só decrementa somente 1 sempre. E a instrução `LOAD` não existe no x86, mas existe `LODSB` ou `LODSW`, que são mais complexos, e são utilizado para operações de STRING (array de dados).

Estou um utilizando o programa do **MS-DOS debug** para depurar.Também funciona com o **SYMDEB.EXE** também do MS-DOS.

Se for utilizar em outra linguagem de alto nível como C, ou pascal, você pode utilizar `label:` antes do loop e `JNZ @label` em vez de `JNZ 0107`.

Comment: O código final será só este?

Comment: Isso, alocação nos registradores, decremento e loop.

Comment: Amigo não entendi muito bem não.

Comment: Você executou o programa?

Comment: deu vários erros, mas acho que eu fiz errado aqui.

Comment: Dependendo do depurador não é possível acessar a memória RAM. E em outros usam EAX em vez de AX, e EBX em vez de BX

Comment: Não e isso amigo, o código tá certo. mas segundo meu professor são as instruções do IAS, maquina era.

Comment: O IAS não é muito conhecido, é outro processador. Geralmente o pessoal ensina o x86 porque é o conjunto de instruções de processadores que a Intel usa desde 1970. Vou olhar como funciona o IAS e te respondo

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture. Qual o programa que você usa para testar isso?

Comment: testamos no gcc do Linux.

Comment: Ah sim, sugiro criar uma nova pergunta, enfatizando que você está trabalhando com GCC e IAS. Se quiser pode criar uma pergunta de como converter o código x86 para IAS, mas acredito que como não existe a tag IAS, raramente vai ter uma resposta.

Comment: segundo meu professor so 2 linhas estão erradas, mas não me disse qual